# Bootstrap Nav - CSS Issue regarding white dots

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have the following which uses Bootstrap, with an image of how it looks in real life:

```
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class=""><a href="/Analyst">Analysts</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Coverage<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="mynavlist">
                        <li><a href="/Coverage/AddCoverageSearch">Add Coverage</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Coverage/Coverage?status=A">All Coverage</a></li>
                        <li id="mycov"><a href="/Coverage/MyCoverage?status=A">My Coverage</a></li>
                        <li class="addborder"><a href=""></a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Coverage/CoverageAssignments?groupingBySector=True">Coverage Assignments</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Holding/PortfolioCoverage">Portfolio Coverage</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Holding/PortfolioSnapshot">Portfolio Snapshot</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Writeup/WriteupSections/34?status=A">Writeup Sections</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/Holding/List">Funds</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Blotter/Account?analystname=Aaron%20Wasserman">Intraday Orders</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Reports</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

[image]

If you look very closely you can see 4 tiny white dots below "Analysts", "Coverage", "Funds", and "Intraday Orders". What are they and how do I get rid of them?

Comment: Zoomed in as far as I could in Photoshop and can't see these white dots...? Some next level perfectionism btw.

Comment: could be `list-style-type` against `li`. Attach the relevant css so we don't need to guess

Comment: I can see the white dots just to the left of the navigation text except Reports.  However, I have put your code into a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karen_quad/shbfectg/) and changed the background and there are no dots:  .  Maybe its from somewhere else in your html page?  Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap v3.3.7, and have tried this rule in my custom css: li { list-style-type: none !important;}, which had no effect. sconner87, I am no perfectionist, I'm just afraid my boss will be... :)

Comment: There must be some other piece of code that is responsible for those white dots, the present code seems fine.

Comment: One would think so, but no. I noticed that Reports does not have a white dot. Also, when you hover over the white dots, the cursor changes to a hand, so the dots are part of the li items...